# Applying case statement on date

Tags: oracle

I am working on reports where we have activity start date(Date when the activity has begun) and activity end date(When the activity ended). I have a requirement wherein if the activity has begun before 2021 then I have to set the start date as 1/1/21 and if it continues after 2021 then set the activity end date as 31/12/21.And if the start date and end date lie in the same year keeping them as it is.
How can I achieve this scenario.

Comment: You seem to know that you can use a case expression, so what issue are you having? You might actually want greatest/least instead, but the "in the same year" is a bit confusing - unclear if that only refers to 2021, or any year. As always, sample data and expected results (as formatted text, not images) would be useful - see [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a `CASE` expression; you can use `GREATEST` and `LEAST`:

```sql
UPDATE table_name
SET    start_date = GREATEST(start_date, DATE '2021-01-01'),
       end_date   = LEAST(end_date, TIMESTAMP '2021-12-31 23:59:59')
WHERE  start_date < DATE '2022-01-01'
AND    (  start_date <  DATE '2021-01-01'
       OR end_date   >= DATE '2022-01-01');
```

---

If you want to just select the values where the date range overlaps 2021, and limit the range to be from 2021, then:

```sql
SELECT column1,
       column2,
       GREATEST(start_date, DATE '2021-01-01') AS start_date,
       LEAST(end_date, TIMESTAMP '2021-12-31 23:59:59') AS end_date
FROM   table_name
WHERE  start_date <  DATE '2022-01-01'
AND    end_date   >= DATE '2021-01-01'
```

---

If you want a generic query for any given year, starting from the `:year_start` bind variable, then:

```sql
SELECT column1,
       column2,
       GREATEST(start_date, :year_start) AS start_date,
       LEAST(end_date, ADD_MONTHS(:year_start, 12) - INTERVAL '1' SECOND) AS end_date
FROM   table_name
WHERE  start_date <  ADD_MONTHS(:year_start, 12)
AND    end_date   >= :year_start;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply..the date can vary..if I am running the report for the current year and the activity start date is from 2021 then I have to set the activity start date as 1/1/22...We would require a generic query which would run for any year

Comment: @AnushreeBakshi Then change the query to use a bind variable for the `:year_start` rather than hardcoding the value. If that is not what you require then you need to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/31951450) your question to give a [MRE] with example data (`CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements) and your expected output.